# Join em quatro tabelas usando LAMBDA

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, expressões-lambda, join, inner-join

[image: Modelo para o JOIN]

Estou batendo cabeça há dois dias para dar JOIN com o LAMBDA nessas tabelas. Estou criando uma SESSION para meu usuário em ASP.NET Core, antes de passar meu objeto para JSON, preciso dar JOIN nessas tabelas. Porém não estou conseguindo, se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço mto. (OBS. Não postei o meu código, pq estou alterando ele constantemente)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente fazer desta froma,  eu não  sei  como  está  o  nome das tabelas  no  seu context então  você  vai  precisar alterar, mas  basicamente é isso

```
var query =  from o in db.office 
    join e db.employee on x.idOffice equals e.OfficeId
    join a db.address on e.idEmployee equals a.EmployeeId
    join d db.devolution on e.idEmployee equals d.EmployeeId
    where o.idOffice == 1
    select o;

 var result = query.ToList()
```

Comment: Man, obrigado, só precisei fazer alguma alterações e deu certo, valeeu

Comment: Por nada, n esquece de marcar como  correto  a resposta e dar up vote :)